# IASK - InAppSettingsKit

Tags: ios, iphone, inappsettingskit

I'm new to `iPhone` development.I'm using `IASK` on my `APP`:

```
Under root.plist, added new preference i.e, "new_preference" BOOL Key with type as PSToggleSwitchSpecifier, default value as NO. I'm able to access "new_preference" default value correctly (as FALSE) on my code using boolForKey:@"new_preference".
```

When I changed:

```
"new_preference" to STRING / INTEGER Key with type as PSTextFieldSpecifier / 

PSMultiValueSpecifier, default value as "abcd" / "123". "new_preference" default value not reflects on my code with string/integerForKey:@"new_preference".
```

Instead of default values it results as "null" / "0" appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

InAppSettingsKit does not change the value of a settings key unless the user actively does. Think of the default value as the setting displayed if the key doesn't exist yet. Since you already set the key with a BOOL value before, this isn't changed.

If you're changing the type of a key, it's your job to convert old types over to the new one.